# HTTP Error 503 when trying to download data from the site

Tags: python, pandas, urllib

Hi i am trying to get table data from site GOGOV. It provides information on vaccination that interests me.

I wrote the following list:

```
query_dataset = 'https://gogov.ru/articles/covid-v-stats'
name_source = 'GHR_Y00011440'
sources = 'https://gogov.ru/covid-v-stats/'

data_list_region = [['RU-MOW', 'msk'], ['RU-MOS', 'mo'], ['RU-SPE', 'spb'], ['RU-KDA', 'krd'], ['RU-ROS', 'rst'], ['RU-BA', 'bash'],
                    ['RU-SVE', 'svo'], ['RU-TT', 'rt'], ['RU-SAM', 'smr'], ['RU-NIZ', 'ngo'], ['RU-BEL', 'blg'], ['RU-NVS', 'nso'],
                    ['RU-CHE', 'chlb'], ['RU-KEM', 'kmr'], ['RU-VGG', 'vlg'], ['RU-KYA', 'kry'], ['RU-SAR', 'srt'],
                    ['RU-IRK', 'irk'], ['RU-VOR', 'vrzh'], ['RU-STA', 'srp'], ['RU-KHM', 'hmao'], ['RU-ALT', 'altkr'],
                    ['RU-PER', 'prm'], ['RU-ORE', 'orb'], ['RU-CR', 'crimea'], ['RU-TYU', 'tmn'], ['RU-TUL', 'tla'], ['RU-OMS', 'omsk'],
                    ['RU-CE', 'che'], ['RU-LEN', 'lo'], ['RU-PRI', 'prim'], ['RU-LIP', 'lpts'], ['RU-KIR', 'krv'], ['RU-BRY', 'brn'],
                    ['RU-SA', 'yak'], ['RU-KRS', 'krsk'], ['RU-TVE', 'tvr'], ['RU-PNZ', 'pnz'], ['RU-ZAB', 'zbk'], ['RU-IVA', 'ivnv'],
                    ['RU-UD', 'udm'], ['RU-BU', 'brt'], ['RU-AST', 'ast'],
                    ['RU-ULY', 'uln'], ['RU-MO', 'mrd'], ['RU-TAM', 'tmb'], ['RU-KHA', 'khbr'], ['RU-KGD', 'klg'],
                    ['RU-CU', 'chvsh'], ['RU-YAR', 'yar'], ['RU-DA', 'dg'], ['RU-TOM', 'tms'], ['RU-ARK', 'arkh'],
                    ['RU-VLG', 'vlgd'], ['RU-KLU', 'klga'], ['RU-RYA', 'rzn'], ['RU-KGN', 'krg'], ['RU-AMU', 'amr'], ['RU-KO', 'kmi'],
                    ['RU-VLA', 'vld'], ['RU-SMO', 'sml'], ['RU-MUR', 'mrm'],
                    ['RU-ORL', 'orl'], ['RU-SAK', 'skhl'], ['RU-YAN', 'yam'], ['RU-KR', 'krl'],
                    ['RU-KOS', 'ktm'], ['RU-NGR', 'nvg'], ['RU-KK', 'khks'], ['RU-SEV', 'sev'], ['RU-PSK', 'psk'], ['RU-ME', 'mrl'],
                    ['RU-KB', 'kbr'], ['RU-IN', 'ing'],
                    ['RU-SE', 'ost'], ['RU-TY', 'tva'],
                    ['RU-KC', 'krch'], ['RU-AD', 'adg'], ['RU-KAM', 'kmch'], ['RU-KL', 'klm'], ['RU-ALT', 'alt'], ['RU-MAG', 'mgd'],
                    ['RU-YEV', 'eao'], ['RU-CHU', 'chuk'], ['RU-NEN', 'nao']]
```

Function to download:

```
def save(source, name, directory, region_code = None):
      ru_region_save = pd.read_html(source, header=0)
      ru_region_save = ru_region_save[0]
      if region_code != None:
          ru_region_save['region_code'] = region_code
      ru_region_save.to_csv(directory + name, index=False)

save(source=query_dataset, name='now.csv', directory=directory)
```

I get the following error, which I think makes it clear that the site sees me as a bot. Even on the site, with an intensive transition from the page, a captcha may appear.

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I manage to get 3 files from 3 pages and then I get an error. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP [503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) means the server is busy and cant serve you at the moment.
You need to try and pause for few seconds between HTTP call to the server.

Comment: I have already done this, sooner or later I get this error again. Even with a delay of a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep  # <<---

query_dataset = 'https://gogov.ru/articles/covid-v-stats'
name_source = 'GHR_Y00011440'
sources = 'https://gogov.ru/covid-v-stats/'

data_list_region = [['RU-MOW', 'msk'], ['RU-MOS', 'mo'], ['RU-SPE', 'spb'], ['RU-KDA', 'krd'], ['RU-ROS', 'rst'], ['RU-BA', 'bash'],
                    ['RU-SVE', 'svo'], ['RU-TT', 'rt'], ['RU-SAM', 'smr'], ['RU-NIZ', 'ngo'], ['RU-BEL', 'blg'], ['RU-NVS', 'nso'],
                    ['RU-CHE', 'chlb'], ['RU-KEM', 'kmr'], ['RU-VGG', 'vlg'], ['RU-KYA', 'kry'], ['RU-SAR', 'srt'],
                    ['RU-IRK', 'irk'], ['RU-VOR', 'vrzh'], ['RU-STA', 'srp'], ['RU-KHM', 'hmao'], ['RU-ALT', 'altkr'],
                    ['RU-PER', 'prm'], ['RU-ORE', 'orb'], ['RU-CR', 'crimea'], ['RU-TYU', 'tmn'], ['RU-TUL', 'tla'], ['RU-OMS', 'omsk'],
                    ['RU-CE', 'che'], ['RU-LEN', 'lo'], ['RU-PRI', 'prim'], ['RU-LIP', 'lpts'], ['RU-KIR', 'krv'], ['RU-BRY', 'brn'],
                    ['RU-SA', 'yak'], ['RU-KRS', 'krsk'], ['RU-TVE', 'tvr'], ['RU-PNZ', 'pnz'], ['RU-ZAB', 'zbk'], ['RU-IVA', 'ivnv'],
                    ['RU-UD', 'udm'], ['RU-BU', 'brt'], ['RU-AST', 'ast'],
                    ['RU-ULY', 'uln'], ['RU-MO', 'mrd'], ['RU-TAM', 'tmb'], ['RU-KHA', 'khbr'], ['RU-KGD', 'klg'],
                    ['RU-CU', 'chvsh'], ['RU-YAR', 'yar'], ['RU-DA', 'dg'], ['RU-TOM', 'tms'], ['RU-ARK', 'arkh'],
                    ['RU-VLG', 'vlgd'], ['RU-KLU', 'klga'], ['RU-RYA', 'rzn'], ['RU-KGN', 'krg'], ['RU-AMU', 'amr'], ['RU-KO', 'kmi'],
                    ['RU-VLA', 'vld'], ['RU-SMO', 'sml'], ['RU-MUR', 'mrm'],
                    ['RU-ORL', 'orl'], ['RU-SAK', 'skhl'], ['RU-YAN', 'yam'], ['RU-KR', 'krl'],
                    ['RU-KOS', 'ktm'], ['RU-NGR', 'nvg'], ['RU-KK', 'khks'], ['RU-SEV', 'sev'], ['RU-PSK', 'psk'], ['RU-ME', 'mrl'],
                    ['RU-KB', 'kbr'], ['RU-IN', 'ing'],
                    ['RU-SE', 'ost'], ['RU-TY', 'tva'],
                    ['RU-KC', 'krch'], ['RU-AD', 'adg'], ['RU-KAM', 'kmch'], ['RU-KL', 'klm'], ['RU-ALT', 'alt'], ['RU-MAG', 'mgd'],
                    ['RU-YEV', 'eao'], ['RU-CHU', 'chuk'], ['RU-NEN', 'nao']]

def save(source, name, directory, region_code = None):
    ru_region_save = pd.read_html(source, header=0)

    # allow the site to pause for breath
    sleep(5) # <<---

    ru_region_save = ru_region_save[0]
    if region_code != None:
        ru_region_save['region_code'] = region_code
    ru_region_save.to_csv(directory + name, index=False)

# I had to use this, but use whatever you need...    
directory = './'

save(source=query_dataset, name='now.csv', directory=directory)
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Additional:**

I can only guess at what to try if the site still fails.  Maybe using requests and setting headers with something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep  # <<--
import requests         # <<--

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}  # <<--

query_dataset = 'https://gogov.ru/articles/covid-v-stats'
name_source = 'GHR_Y00011440'
sources = 'https://gogov.ru/covid-v-stats/'

data_list_region = [['RU-MOW', 'msk'], ['RU-MOS', 'mo'], ['RU-SPE', 'spb'], ['RU-KDA', 'krd'], ['RU-ROS', 'rst'], ['RU-BA', 'bash'],
                    ['RU-SVE', 'svo'], ['RU-TT', 'rt'], ['RU-SAM', 'smr'], ['RU-NIZ', 'ngo'], ['RU-BEL', 'blg'], ['RU-NVS', 'nso'],
                    ['RU-CHE', 'chlb'], ['RU-KEM', 'kmr'], ['RU-VGG', 'vlg'], ['RU-KYA', 'kry'], ['RU-SAR', 'srt'],
                    ['RU-IRK', 'irk'], ['RU-VOR', 'vrzh'], ['RU-STA', 'srp'], ['RU-KHM', 'hmao'], ['RU-ALT', 'altkr'],
                    ['RU-PER', 'prm'], ['RU-ORE', 'orb'], ['RU-CR', 'crimea'], ['RU-TYU', 'tmn'], ['RU-TUL', 'tla'], ['RU-OMS', 'omsk'],
                    ['RU-CE', 'che'], ['RU-LEN', 'lo'], ['RU-PRI', 'prim'], ['RU-LIP', 'lpts'], ['RU-KIR', 'krv'], ['RU-BRY', 'brn'],
                    ['RU-SA', 'yak'], ['RU-KRS', 'krsk'], ['RU-TVE', 'tvr'], ['RU-PNZ', 'pnz'], ['RU-ZAB', 'zbk'], ['RU-IVA', 'ivnv'],
                    ['RU-UD', 'udm'], ['RU-BU', 'brt'], ['RU-AST', 'ast'],
                    ['RU-ULY', 'uln'], ['RU-MO', 'mrd'], ['RU-TAM', 'tmb'], ['RU-KHA', 'khbr'], ['RU-KGD', 'klg'],
                    ['RU-CU', 'chvsh'], ['RU-YAR', 'yar'], ['RU-DA', 'dg'], ['RU-TOM', 'tms'], ['RU-ARK', 'arkh'],
                    ['RU-VLG', 'vlgd'], ['RU-KLU', 'klga'], ['RU-RYA', 'rzn'], ['RU-KGN', 'krg'], ['RU-AMU', 'amr'], ['RU-KO', 'kmi'],
                    ['RU-VLA', 'vld'], ['RU-SMO', 'sml'], ['RU-MUR', 'mrm'],
                    ['RU-ORL', 'orl'], ['RU-SAK', 'skhl'], ['RU-YAN', 'yam'], ['RU-KR', 'krl'],
                    ['RU-KOS', 'ktm'], ['RU-NGR', 'nvg'], ['RU-KK', 'khks'], ['RU-SEV', 'sev'], ['RU-PSK', 'psk'], ['RU-ME', 'mrl'],
                    ['RU-KB', 'kbr'], ['RU-IN', 'ing'],
                    ['RU-SE', 'ost'], ['RU-TY', 'tva'],
                    ['RU-KC', 'krch'], ['RU-AD', 'adg'], ['RU-KAM', 'kmch'], ['RU-KL', 'klm'], ['RU-ALT', 'alt'], ['RU-MAG', 'mgd'],
                    ['RU-YEV', 'eao'], ['RU-CHU', 'chuk'], ['RU-NEN', 'nao']]

def save(source, name, directory, region_code = None):
    ru_region_save = pd.read_html(requests.get(source, headers=headers).text)    # <<--
    sleep(5)    # <<--
    ru_region_save = ru_region_save[0]
    if region_code != None:
        ru_region_save['region_code'] = region_code
    ru_region_save.to_csv(directory + name, index=False)

# whatever you need..    
directory = './'


save(source=query_dataset, name='now.csv', directory=directory)
```

Comment: I have already done this, sooner or later I get this error again. Even with a delay of a few minutes

Comment: I can only answer based on the code you have posted in the question.  That's fair right?  Maybe the site is trying to stop scraping?  I cannot read Russian so I cannot see if there are terms and conditions on scraping etc.  Sometimes they say no, sometimes yes.  Maybe they have a different url for data access?  You haven't shown in the question if you are using headers.  Who knows :o(.

Comment: @kostyaivanov I've updated the answer.  Maybe it works.  Just a thought and as correction to my last comment about headers: I saw in the original code `header=0`.